# List of months between two dates as month & year

Tags: date, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

How do I get a dynamic list of months down a column between two dates in the month year format in Google Sheets?

example:

```
Start date: 5/18/2016
End date: 5/24/2019
```

---

```
Jan 2016
Feb 2016
Mar 2016
..
...
May 2019
```

Answer (score 7):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TEXT(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&DATEVALUE(B1)):
 INDIRECT("B"&DATEVALUE(B2)))), "mmm yyyy")))
```

[image]